# I could not import exported variables from an es2015 NPM module

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, webpack

I have an npm module named `sidebar`. I use `webpack` to compile the es2015 src files into a single file. So far running `webpack` does not output any problem and creates a file, `lib/sidebar.min.js`

I have set the it to be the main file in `package.json`

```
...
"description": "",
"main": "lib/sidebar.min.js",
"scripts": {
...
```

I have this in my `src/index.js` file

```
export const foo = 'foo'
export const bar = 'bar'
```

I tried using this module in my main project

```
import { foo, bar } from 'sidebar'
console.log(foo)
console.log(bar)
```

Both console log calls outputs `undefined`

After searching the internet for hours, I am totally stumped as to why this is a problem.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is the `webpack` config for the main repository

```
var webpackConfig = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/app/main.app.js',
        vendor: ['angular']
    },
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIRECTORY + '/scripts/',
        publicPath: '/scripts/',
        filename: '[name].min.js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].min.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel'
        }, {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'raw'
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                unused: true,
                dead_code: true
            },
            sourceMap: true
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("vendor", "vendor.bundle.js")
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: DIST_DIRECTORY + '/'
    }
};
```

Comment: Maybe post you webpack.config.js ?

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question - but is `sidebar/lib/sidebar.min.js` being generated? To me it looks like you're outputting it to `lib/scripts/sidebar.min.js`

Comment: This is the webpack config for the main project. The `sidebar` is in a npm module.